# What is the correct way to schedule periodic events in Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Simple question, I would hope: I'm writing an application in which I want to retrieve data from a database; I've elected to use Rx for this purpose to represent the database as a sequence of values.

I only want to poll the database (and thus have my observer's notifications occur) at a maximum of once every 5 seconds. Right now, I have something like this, where the Scheduler is scheduling a periodic task that causes my observer to be subscribed to the observable that is my database:

```
_scheduler.SchedulePeriodic(_repository, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    (repo) => repo.AsObservable()
        .Where(item => _SomeFilter(item))
        .Subscribe(item => _SomeProcessFunction(item))
);
```

Function names and the like omitted for brevity; `repo.AsObservable()` is simply a function that returns an `IObservable<T>` of all the items inside the repository at that point.

Now, I figure that this is the correct way of doing things, however before I came up with this solution I did come up with a different solution in which I had an `Observable.Timer` with the subscribed observer would subscribe to the `AsObservable()` return value every timer tick instead.

My question is that this seems very.. odd - why am I subscribing multiple times to the observable?

Sorry if this question is confusing, it confused me while writing it, however the schedulers are also confusing for me :P

Comment: Without the wider context I don't know if this makes sense; but since polling makes me itchy, I thought I'd ruminate on whether you have the opportunity to send a message from the originators of any updates to which your observer can subscribe and thus avoid a polling solution in favour of something more service oriented - appreciate this may not be possible or practical, but thought I'd point it out in case it hadn't been considered.

Comment: I would definitely like to avoid polling wherever possible. However, I don't have any idea on where to start with making the database notify me when there's new items. And I didn't understand half of the words you used in your comment.

Comment: I think what James is suggesting is a secondary notification system for updates. Any number of components can update the database, and any number might need to know that. If the database itself is capable of communicating these changes, that's great. If not, a secondary system may be used to communicate that changes have been made (push) and the components will then query for the changes (pull). This would alleviate the need for polling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you use the built in operators instead of manually scheduling tasks?

```
repo.AsObservable()
    .Where(_SomeFilter)
    // Wait 5 seconds before completing
    .Concat(Observable.Empty<T>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    // Resubscribe indefinitely after source completes
    .Repeat()
    // Subscribe
    .Subscribe(_SomeProcessFunction);
```

Comment: That didn't occur to me, probably because it wasn't obvious - at least to me. Still an interesting solution that definitely gets the job done.

Comment: The problem with using a scheduler directly is that you'll need to track the duration of queries to ensure only one is running at a time, and you'll need to track a the queries themselves for hygienic reasons. In this code, the first query is run immediately, and another query starts 5 seconds after the previous one finishes. It ensures you don't need to track the success of each query or the disposables, since `Repeat` and `Concat(Delay)` are taking care of that for you.

Comment: It helps to try to think of your problem in sequences of data. This  should help lead you to solutions like Christopher's one above. Instead of imperatively telling things when and how to do something, describe the sequence you want to create.

Comment: I would note (for anyone stumbling across this) that it's still important to pass in a scheduler for unit testing purposes. This code, as written, takes a minimum 5 seconds to run a unit test. That's a problem if you have a dozen tests to run against this code, or code like it. A scheduler (or TestScheduler more accurately) allows you to "fake" the passage of time to test what would normally be long running processes very quickly.